# Properties of the solution of an initial value problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an IVP which can not be solved for explicitly of the form:

$y''(t) = f(y)(y')^2 +ay'-g(y)$

$y(0)=0, y'(x_1) = h(y)>0$

with $y,y',y'' \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $x \in [0,x_1]$ and I know that the solution is unique and continuous.

Can I somehow figure out more properties of the solution, given functions some properties of the functions $f(\cdot)$, $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$, e.g. if it is increasing/decreasing/convex/concave on some interval or has a minimum/maximum value somewhere?

Is it, in general even possible to do something like that? I would be happy about every kind of suggestion / reference, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, one can figure out something about $y$ without solving the equation. This typically involves looking at the specific $f,g,h$, $a$, scratching one's head and scribbling estimates for a prolonged period of time. There is no general recipe.

Comment: @Fundamental Thanks! That explains why I wasn't able to find anything about that. So, I guess it is more scratching and scribbling for me then. If anyone has an  example on how one could figure out anything for some chosen functions/parameters or an idea of what could be a good candidate to test or testing strategy, I would be happy to accept an answer including that + the comment that there is no general way.